# How to connect a database?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I am doing a REST API realization of the blog
Here is the code for my main app

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify
from flask_jwt import JWT
import hmac
from datetime import timedelta
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from resources.author import author_api
from resources.category import category_api
from resources.post import post_api
from models.author import Author

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'postgresql://:123@localhost/blog'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
app.config['JWT_SECRET_KEY'] = 'super-secret'
app.config['JWT_EXPIRATION_DELTA'] = timedelta(hours=1)

db = SQLAlchemy()

with app.app_context():
    db.init_app(app)
    db.create_all()

def authenticate(username, password):
    author = Author.query.filter_by(login=username).first()

    if author and hmac.compare_digest(author.password.encode('utf-8'), password.encode('utf-8')):
        return author

def identity(payload):
    author_id = payload['identity']
    return Author.query.filter_by(id=author_id).first()

jwt = JWT(app, authenticate, identity)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return jsonify({'message': 'Welcome to the blog API!'})

app.register_blueprint(author_api, url_prefix='/api')
app.register_blueprint(category_api, url_prefix='/api')
app.register_blueprint(post_api, url_prefix='/api')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

But i have got an error. After researching about it it seems like a problem with a connection to database. Have no idea how to fix it. Server is running and all the connection data are correct.
Here is an error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\projects\projects for fun\blog\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 145, in __init__
    self._dbapi_connection = engine.raw_connection()
  File "D:\projects\projects for fun\blog\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 3269, in raw_connection
    return self.pool.connect()
  File "D:\projects\projects for fun\blog\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 455, in connect
    return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)
  File "D:\projects\projects for fun\blog\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 1270, in _checkout
    fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)
  File "D:\projects\projects for fun\blog\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 719, in checkout
    rec = pool._do_get()
  File "D:\projects\projects for fun\blog\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\impl.py", line 168, in _do_get
    with util.safe_reraise():
  File "D:\projects\projects for fun\blog\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\langhelpers.py", line 147, in __exit__
    raise exc_value.with_traceback(exc_tb)
  File "D:\projects\projects for fun\blog\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\impl.py", line 166, in _do_get
    return self._create_connection()
  File "D:\projects\projects for fun\blog\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 396, in _create_connection
    return _ConnectionRecord(self)
  File "D:\projects\projects for fun\blog\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 681, in __init__
    self.__connect()
  File "D:\projects\projects for fun\blog\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 905, in __connect
    with util.safe_reraise():
  File "D:\projects\projects for fun\blog\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\langhelpers.py", line 147, in __exit__
    raise exc_value.with_traceback(exc_tb)
  File "D:\projects\projects for fun\blog\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 901, in __connect
    self.dbapi_connection = connection = pool._invoke_creator(self)
  File "D:\projects\projects for fun\blog\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\create.py", line 640, in connect
    return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "D:\projects\projects for fun\blog\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 580, in connect
    return self.loaded_dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "D:\projects\projects for fun\blog\venv\lib\site-packages\psycopg2\__init__.py", line 122, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\projects\projects for fun\blog\app.py", line 22, in <module>
    db.create_all()
  File "D:\projects\projects for fun\blog\venv\lib\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy\extension.py", line 884, in create_all
    self._call_for_binds(bind_key, "create_all")
  File "D:\projects\projects for fun\blog\venv\lib\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy\extension.py", line 865, in _call_for_binds
    getattr(metadata, op_name)(bind=engine)
  File "D:\projects\projects for fun\blog\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\schema.py", line 5576, in create_all
    bind._run_ddl_visitor(
  File "D:\projects\projects for fun\blog\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 3219, in _run_ddl_visitor
    with self.begin() as conn:
  File "C:\Users\andre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\contextlib.py", line 135, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "D:\projects\projects for fun\blog\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 3209, in begin
    with self.connect() as conn:
  File "D:\projects\projects for fun\blog\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 3245, in connect
    return self._connection_cls(self)
  File "D:\projects\projects for fun\blog\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 147, in __init__
    Connection._handle_dbapi_exception_noconnection(
  File "D:\projects\projects for fun\blog\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 2410, in _handle_dbapi_exception_noconnection
    raise sqlalchemy_exception.with_traceback(exc_info[2]) from e
  File "D:\projects\projects for fun\blog\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 145, in __init__
    self._dbapi_connection = engine.raw_connection()
  File "D:\projects\projects for fun\blog\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 3269, in raw_connection
    return self.pool.connect()
  File "D:\projects\projects for fun\blog\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 455, in connect
    return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)
  File "D:\projects\projects for fun\blog\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 1270, in _checkout
    fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)
  File "D:\projects\projects for fun\blog\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 719, in checkout
    rec = pool._do_get()
  File "D:\projects\projects for fun\blog\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\impl.py", line 168, in _do_get
    with util.safe_reraise():
  File "D:\projects\projects for fun\blog\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\langhelpers.py", line 147, in __exit__
    raise exc_value.with_traceback(exc_tb)
  File "D:\projects\projects for fun\blog\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\impl.py", line 166, in _do_get
    return self._create_connection()
  File "D:\projects\projects for fun\blog\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 396, in _create_connection
    return _ConnectionRecord(self)
  File "D:\projects\projects for fun\blog\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 681, in __init__
    self.__connect()
  File "D:\projects\projects for fun\blog\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 905, in __connect
    with util.safe_reraise():
  File "D:\projects\projects for fun\blog\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\langhelpers.py", line 147, in __exit__
    raise exc_value.with_traceback(exc_tb)
  File "D:\projects\projects for fun\blog\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 901, in __connect
    self.dbapi_connection = connection = pool._invoke_creator(self)
  File "D:\projects\projects for fun\blog\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\create.py", line 640, in connect
    return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "D:\projects\projects for fun\blog\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 580, in connect
    return self.loaded_dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "D:\projects\projects for fun\blog\venv\lib\site-packages\psycopg2\__init__.py", line 122, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) 
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/e3q8)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I have tried debugging it with chatgpt and read the documentation for sqlachemy and postgresql

Answer (score 0):

`'postgresql://:123@localhost/blog'` is suspicious as a database URI. It means no username and password "123". The format is `postgresql://username:password@server/db`

Comment: Yeah, I Know this is local project so empty username takes a default username of pc and password is 123. There is no difference will I leave empty space instead of username or write it(in this case)